# How to link a google calendar event to a form which edits the event?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

New to Google Apps Script, is there a way to link a calendar event to a form that edits the guest list and description of the event.

Note: The users can't directly edit everything in the event, just change certain values through the form interface, but not delete the description, so a link to a form would work.

Comment: This is all possible but is too broad a question to get a specific answer.

Comment: I would not use a Google Form to do this.  I would use a Web App.  You could generate and Edit URL for an existing Google Form response that would have code to edit the calendar event.  It order to get an Edit URL, there first needs to be a Form Submission.  But there needs to be a way to provide the user with the Edit URL.  The Edit URL could be emailed to the person, or the user could go to a Web App and enter a calendar date.  But if the starting point is a Web App, maybe you'd want to do it all in a Web App.  I don't know of a nice easy way to get this done or existing code.